# JavaFX GraphicContext.fillText() format

Tags: java, javafx

I have canvas with GraphicsContext on it and I am wondering if it is possible to format `.fillText()` method in any way?

```
GraphicsContext gc = getGraphicsContext2D();
gc.setTextAlign(TextAlignment.CENTER);
gc.setTextBaseline(VPos.CENTER);
gc.fillText(someString, Math.round(width / 2), Math.round(height / 2));
```

I want to make every character in `someString` with different color and keep this text centered

And it is not possible. This `Canvas` and `Pane` are resizable (`Canvas` width and height properties are binded to `Pane` width and height and `Canvas` is redrawn every time `Pane` size changes). So the question is, how can i create `Text` object or any other text object so it would be always in the center of `Pane`

Comment: I don't know JavaFX that well but assuming it is still similar to Swing in that case you'd probably have to set the color `gc` between letters and calculate the character position yourself. But is that really what you want to do? Swing already had components that allow you to render formatted text (e.g. using HTML) and JavaFX should support that as well.

Comment: Yes, if canvas is not a requirement, you can use javafx textflow. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html

Comment: lets assume that canvas is a requirement. It just seems like a very simple and obvious operation. But in case if it can't be done, then it can't be done.

Comment: If you are required to use a `Canvas` for some reason, I think the plan outlined by @Thomas is essentially the only way to do this.

Comment: AFAIK using canvas is a very low level approach that provides a high level of freedom but also requires you to do many things yourself (like calculating the position of individual characters). More high level functionality normally provides what you want to do and is built on top of low lever functionality like canvas etc. but also introduces constraints that allow for reduced complexity and higher performance. So you'd probably either end up doing most of the stuff yourself or using some higher level concepts.